# Weird problem with input encoding in IPython

Tags: python, windows, filesystems, locale, ipython

I'm running python 2.6 with latest IPython on Windows XP SP3, and I have two questions. First one of my problems is, when under IPython, I cannot input Unicode strings directly, and, as a result, cannot open files with non-latin names. Let me demonstrate. Under usual python this works:

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'mbcs'
>>> fd = open(u'm:/Блокнот/home.tdl')
>>> print u'm:/Блокнот/home.tdl'
m:/Блокнот/home.tdl
>>>
```

It's cyrillic in there, by the way. And under the IPython I get:

```
In [49]: sys.getdefaultencoding()
Out[49]: 'ascii'

In [50]: sys.getfilesystemencoding()
Out[50]: 'mbcs'

In [52]: fd = open(u'm:/Блокнот/home.tdl')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

C:\Documents and Settings\andrey\<ipython console> in <module>()

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'm:/\x81\xab\xae\xaa\xad\xae\xe2/home.tdl'

In [53]: print u'm:/Блокнот/home.tdl'
-------------->print(u'm:/Блокнот/home.tdl')
ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (15, 0))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

C:\Documents and Settings\andrey\<ipython console> in <module>()

C:\Program Files\Python26\lib\encodings\cp866.pyc in encode(self, input, errors)
     10
     11     def encode(self,input,errors='strict'):
---> 12         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
     13
     14     def decode(self,input,errors='strict'):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 3-9: character maps to <und

In [54]:
```

The second problem is less frustrating, but still. When I try to open a file, and specify file name argument as non-unicode string, it does not open. I have to **forcibly** decode string from OEM charset, before I could open files, which is pretty inconvenient:

```
>>> fd2 = open('m:/Блокнот/home.tdl'.decode('cp866'))
>>>
```

Maybe it has something to with my regional settings, I don't know, because I can't even cut-and-paste cyrillic text from console. I've put "Russian" everywhere in regional settings, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Typing Unicode at the console is always problematic and generally best avoided, but [IPython is particularly broke](http://projects.scipy.org/ipython/ipython/ticket/239). It converts characters you type on its console as if they were encoded in ISO-8859-1, regardless of the actual encoding you're giving it.

For now, you'll have to say `u'm:/\u0411\u043b\u043e\u043a\u043d\u043e\u0442/home.tdl'`.

Comment: Oh, ok. That's sad, though. Will wait for fix.

Comment: Here is patch for this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ipython/+bug/339642

Just remove line 'source=source.encode(self.stdin_encoding)' from iplib.py from IPython distribution. It worked for me in OS X.

Comment: @t0ster: thank you for the tip, worked for me. And to think I have spent several hours googling thinking this is an issue of Matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

Perversely enough, this will work:

```
fd = open('m:/Блокнот/home.tdl')
```

Or:

```
fd = open('m:/Блокнот/home.tdl'.encode('utf-8'))
```

This gets around ipython's bug by inputting the string as a raw UTF-8 encoded byte-string. ipython doesn't try any funny business with it. You're then free to encode it into a unicode string if you like, and get on with your life.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Greek input, this [patch from launchpad](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ipython/+bug/339642) works for me too.

Thanks.